# php play video anchor links in new tab of browser only if its in the session

Tags: php, jquery, video

I am new to php. I am having anchor links each will play a video in new tab after clicking on it.

So the problem is: If anyone knows the exact url of video, they can paste that url in browser and can watch the video, which should not happen. But currently this is the issue I am having.

I knew that we can do this by checking with sessions, but not understanding in a programmatic approach. I tried in other way using html5 video links too, but has no luck that way either.

Kindly provide me some great solution for my above issue.

**Below are the video anchor links :**

```
<a href="videos/MyVideo1.mp4">MyVideo1</a>
<a href="videos/MyVideo2.mp4">MyVideo2</a>
<a href="videos/MyVideo3.mp4">MyVideo3</a>
```

Comment: So do I understand correctly that you want just not allow that people can save the URL to the mp4 file and then just share it or see it directly without accessing it from your webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I programmed a webpage which can stream videos for logged in users. I didn't made a direct link reference to the video file, I put the video files in a private directory not accessible via browser which is readable by the PHP files. Then the links to the video files were all looking like this: `<a href='stream.php?id=[id]'>Video</a>` where the id is a randomly generated string which is saved and valid for a limited time. So when someone has this link to the stream.php script he cannot use it as the id will be invalid at a later time. And the php script just takes the mp4 file out of the private directory and puts it to output. It's also possible to make the stream.php script able to handle jumps during watching the video.